# Security Group subpanel not showing in main modules

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Security Groups subpanel is not showing in main modules such as Accounts, the relationship and the subpanel are both appearing in studio, but not in the detail view of the account. When I checked my log I found this:

> Bad subpanel definition, it has incorrect value for get_subpanel_data
>   property securitygroups.

I am using SuiteCRM Version 7.7.8 ( based on Sugar CE Version 6.5.24).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution :

In "modules/Accounts/vardefs.php" for unknown reason it missed "security_groups" declaration in this line of code :

VardefManager::createVardef('Accounts','Account', array('default', 'assignable','**security_groups**',
'company',
));